# Using $this in closure by calling bindTo

Tags: php

Consider the following code, why it still throws an error said `Using $this when not in object context` even I used the  `bindTo` function to set the context of `Class A`

```
class A {

    protected $name = 'a';

    function _do(Closure $something) {
        $var = function()use ($something) {
            // suppose to bind the instance of class a for $something
            $something->bindTo($this); 
            $something();
        };
        $var();
    }

}

$a = new A();
$a->_do(function() {
    // using $this as an instance of class A
    echo $this->name;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bindTo` returns a new anonymous function. It doesn't alter the existing one. Change your invoked function to the result of the call to `bindTo`

```php
function _do(Closure $something) {
        $var = function()use ($something) {
            // suppose to bind the instance of class a for $something
            $newSomething = $something->bindTo($this); 
            $newSomething();
        };
        $var();
    }
```